# How we can prove this vector identity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differentiation, vector-fields

I was trying to rederive the formula of the angular momentum of electromagnetic field, and all the steps are clear for me except this one which I took from
"Photons and Atoms: Introduction to Quantum Electrodynamics" by Claude Cohen‐Tannoudji

$$\sum_aU\nabla_a(r\times\nabla)A_{\bot a}=U(r\times\nabla)(\nabla\cdot A_{\bot})-U(\nabla\times A_{\bot})$$

Where $U$ is the Coulomb potential, $$A_{\bot}$$ is the transvers vector potential and $ a$ is sub scripts run from 1 to 3. (like $x,y,z$).
Can any one help me how we get this result? I tried all vector identities I know.

Comment: Hello! I have provided an edit to your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Since the picture was rather blurry, I couldn't identify some of the smaller symbols - feel free to change them if I guessed incorrectly!

Comment: You need to explain what the $a$ subscripts are.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. What (type of objects) are $U$, $A_\perp$ and $a$? At the very least, you should include a detailed reference to *where* in your reference this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U and the perpendicular sub-index are irrelavent. I will omit them.

Some index expressions:
$$
\nabla_a = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_a} \\
\nabla \cdot A = \sum_i \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_i}\\
   \nabla \times A = \sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}\\
\vec{r} = \sum_i x_i \hat{e}_i\\
   \vec{r} \times \nabla = \sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\\
$$
where $\hat{e}_k$ is the unit vector in $k$th direction,  and $ \epsilon_{k i j}$ the Levi-Civita function. The Levi-Civita function is anti-symmetric, changes sign when exchange two indexes.

$$
\sum_a \nabla_a(r\times\nabla)A_{ a} 
= \sum_a \frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}(\sum_k \hat{e}_k\sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{a i j} x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})A_{ a} \\
= \sum_a \sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_a} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}A_{ a} 
 + \sum_a \sum_k \hat{e}_k\sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_a}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}A_{ a} \\
= \sum_a \sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} \delta_{ai}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}A_{ a} 
 + \sum_k \hat{e}_k\sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left\{\sum_a \frac{\partial A_a}{\partial x_a} \right\} \\
= \sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}A_{i} 
 + \sum_k \hat{e}_k\sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left\{ \sum_a \frac{\partial A_a}{\partial x_a} \right\} \\
= -\sum_k \hat{e}_k \sum_j \sum_i \epsilon_{k j i} \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_j} 
 + \left\{\sum_k \hat{e}_k\sum_i \sum_j \epsilon_{k i j} x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\} \left\{ \sum_a \frac{\partial A_a}{\partial x_a} \right\} \\
= - (\nabla\times A) + (r\times\nabla)(\nabla\cdot A)
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. Your answer is so clear and valuable to me.